# Three instances of innerHTML are working, the fourth is not

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm completely new to programming, so please be patient with me.  I only recently finished a large chunk of Codecademy, and read a few books, so I'm most definitely a noob.  I've set up a function that iterates through the results of a Google Places library call through the Google Maps API, and writes properties of the returned object to elements in my HTML.  I did this successfully with the first three instances of innerHTML (using some help from the stackoverflow community, thanks everyone!).  I'm encountering a huge problem with the fourth instance.

I made a call the the Distance Matrix service that Google Maps offers, and I finally got it to work after a few hours of tinkering, since the console.log command seems to be returning what I want.  But foodDistance[0].innerHTML = distance is NOT WORKING!  And it's driving me crazy.  Here's my code so you know what I'm talking about, in case it's unclear:

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        createMarker(place);
        var foodName = foodArray[i].getElementsByClassName("listing_name");
        var foodRating = foodArray[i].getElementsByClassName("listing_rating");
        var foodAddress = foodArray[i].getElementsByClassName("listing_address");
        var foodDistance = foodArray[i].getElementsByClassName("listing_dist");
        foodName[0].innerHTML = place.name;
        foodRating[0].innerHTML = place.rating;
        foodAddress[0].innerHTML = place.vicinity;
        distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [houston],
            destinations: [place.geometry.location],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
          }, distanceCallback);
        function distanceCallback(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
              var origins = response.originAddresses;
              for (var x = 0; x < origins.length; x++) {
                var results = response.rows[x].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                  var element = results[j];
                  var distance = element.distance.text;
                  foodDistance[0].innerHTML = distance;
                  console.log(distance);
                }
              }
            }
          };
        };
      }
    }
```

And here is the HTML with filler content.  listing_name, listing_rating, and listing_address all populate as expected:

```
 <div class="hyperlocal_listing_snippet" id="fd1">
  <div class="listing_name">Stephen's bombass burritos</div>
  <div class="listing_dist">0.2 Miles</div>
  <div class="listing_address">blah blah blah</div>
  <div class="listing_rating">3.2</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the feedback.  What is driving me crazy is the fact that the first three work perfectly, but the fourth one just isn't cooperating.  I'm either looking for a fresh set of eyes to help me pick out my stupid noob mistake, or I'm looking for an explanation as to why this isn't working.  Thanks!

Comment: It should work if foodDistance[0] exists. Make sure     foodDistance[0] is not null. Without seeing HTML we cant check it

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to post the whole thing because it was very lengthy, but foodDistance[0] does exist and is not set to null.  It's set with filler content, like foodName[0], foodAddress[0], and foodRating[0].  I'll update my original post so you can see the HTML.

Comment: Annnnd....each snippet is located in an array named foodDistance.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't being set to something, then changed to blank in a later loop iteration? Maybe google puts a NULL element on the end? What does the console actually say when you run it? What does console.log(foodDistance) say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are suffering from the classic problem of asynchronous functions in a loop.

Try adding this right after the `for(...) {` line:

```
(function(i) {
```

And this right before the corrsponding `}`:

```
})(i);
```

This will "anchor" the value of `i` and solve your problem.

Comment: It flippin' worked!  Thank you so much for answering my question at midnight on a Sunday.  You deserve every one of 77,973 reputation points.  I would upvote, but I don't have enough points.  My noob status shines so bright.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your function `distanceCallback` is asynchronus function. When this call back function `distanceCallback` is called `foodDistance[0]` contains a invalid or different value because you are updating  variable `foodDistance` in `for` loop in the parent function